# Best Practises for outputting dynamic PHP data

Tags: php, html, output

I'm building a website using an API and I'm receiving data from said API using PHP.
When it comes to actually outputting that data elegantly, I always trip up as I always feel as though I'm doing it the wrong way.

At the moment I just have my looooooooong php code at the start of the file and then I just write the html at the bottom and use this sort of syntax to output the data:

```
<div id="user-info">
<h4><?= $user->name; ?></h4>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($user->orders as $order): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><?= $order->ref; ?></a>
        </li> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

However, I feel having a huge amount of PHP followed by all the HTML isn't the most elegant solution and therefore probably isn't the best solution. I assume there is some sort of practise of splitting the files and generating dynamic data on a different page and then parsing that data to the html page when requested. But would that actually make a difference as its not like its multithreaded?

Comment: Did you read about "PHP MVC"?

Answer (score 0):

Load times, which are often not reduced by separating code and representation, are not the only reason to do so: Here are some random others:

- Manageability: Code and graphics might be written/debugged/maintained by different people
- Reuse: You might want to use the same code to create different representations (e.g. different stores with the same logic)
- Caching: You might be able to cache a HTML sniplet (e.g. an order)

These can often be achieved by using a templating engine, i.e. completely separate the HTML representation from the PHP code.

For our apps, there is a strict `no echo or print ever under any circumstances outside of debugging` policy, but ofcourse YMMV.